# Selecting adjacent polygon in vector layer in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to change feature of all polygon's with in 100 radians of given lat long.

initially i used buffer but instead of highlight polygon's it creating as new layer. below is the code i have tried

```
var poitnExtent=features[i].getGeometry().getExtent();
        var bufferedExtent = new ol.extent.buffer(poitnExtent,100);
        //console.log(bufferedExtent);
        var bufferPolygon = new ol.geom.Polygon(
        [
            [[bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[1]],
            [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[3]],
            [bufferedExtent[2], bufferedExtent[3]],
            [bufferedExtent[2], bufferedExtent[1]],
            [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[1]]]
        ]
        );
        var bufferedFeature = new ol.Feature(bufferPolygon);//console.log(vectorBuffers.getSource());

        map.addLayer(vectorBuffers);
        vectorBuffers.getSource().addFeature(bufferedFeature);
```

Comment: 100 radians is a **long** way

Comment: its like 100km we need to do.....